# In C# how can i keep my Treeview node selected upon refresh

Tags: c#, treeview, refresh, selected, treenode

I'm really new to coding
I have a treeview that refreshes with a timer.
How can i make sure i keep my selected node highlighted every time it refreshes

Appreciate any help
Thanks

Here is the code that I have:

```
    private void PopulateTree(ListObjectsResponse buckets)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        List<TreeItem> items = new List<TreeItem>();
        foreach (S3Object obj in buckets.S3Objects)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(obj.Key));
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        existingBucketName = label3.Text + "-DP";
        AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();
        ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest
        {
            BucketName = existingBucketName,
        };

        try
        {
            ListObjectsResponse listResponse;
            listResponse = client.ListObjects(listRequest);
            PopulateTree(listResponse);
        }
        catch
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("There is no folder for this user");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Store selected node to the local variable, refresh, set selected node from the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `o.Key` is a string, and that each string is unique and occurs at most once in `buckets.S3Objects`, try saving the selected value before repopulating the `TreeView`, then select it again afterwards.

```
private void PopulateTree(ListObjectsResponse buckets)
{
    // Since you're about to clear out all current TreeNode instances, storing a
    // reference to SelectedNode is not enough. You're setting o.Key as the Text
    // for each TreeNode, so save the selected node's Text value. 
    var selectedText
        = treeView1.SelectedNode == null ? "" : treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;

    // Repopulate your TreeView with new TreeNodes
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(buckets.S3Objects.Select(o => new TreeNode(o.Key)).ToArray())

    // Look for the TreeNode with the same Text that you had selected before.
    // If it's not found, then SelectedNode will be set to null
    treeView1.SelectedNode =
        = treeView1.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>()
                         .SingleOrDefault(n => n.Text == selectedText);
}
```

Several of the above methods, such as `Select`, `Cast`, and `SingleOrDefault`, are part of LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. I entered in the code and it looks like it does not like the line treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(buckets.S3Objects.Select(o => new TreeNode(o.Key))) - as I said I am only new at this so hopefully i'm not just making a rookie error

Comment: This isn't working for me if I have a sub-node selected. The final line only appears to be searching the top-level nodes. In the debugger treeView1.Nodes is just the top-level ones. Does anyone have a succinct way to search the entire tree for the previous selection?

Comment: If you were able to use SelectedNode.Name when remembering your previous selection, then you can use the following to reselect it, which will work for sub-nodes: `treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find(selectedText, searchAllChildren: true).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is ASP.NET (not ASP.NET MVC) that you're talking about, you would do this in the `Page_Load()` event handler.  Be sure to check whether `IsPostBack == true`

For example,

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    // set selected node here
  }
}
```

If you are using ASP.NET MVC then just store the property in the ViewBag.